# How to get data from a child in Firebase Database?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling to get data from a child in my Database to settext in a `TextView`.

Here is my Database:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJAvp.png)

I think the problem is that I don't have the Uid right after `Ansatte` but the `name` instead.
If I take away `name`, and just have `Ansatte`,Uid, and the rest of the data it works.

Here is my code for getting data:

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("").getReference("Ansatte");
    btnadd = (findViewById(R.id.btn_leggtilansatt));

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();




    tvtest = findViewById(R.id.tvtest);

    databaseReference.child(currentid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists()){
                String user = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

                tvtest.setText(user);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

And here is the code for storing:

```
private void add() {
    String name = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
    String storage = editText3.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = tv.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){





        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()){

                    Ansatt ansatt = new Ansatt (name, email, storage);

                    databaseAnsatt.child(name).child(mAuth.getUid()).setValue(ansatt);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hei" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).toString().trim();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddEmployeeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to get the value of the `name` field that exists under the following location:

```
root/Ansatte/Name/$uid
```

Please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = db.child("Ansatte").child("Name").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            tvtest.setText(name);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
name
```

And this value will be also set to your `tvtest` TextView.

---

P.S. Don't forget to have set the proper security rules.

Comment: Hi, this helped. I've accepted your answer! Thank you